# react-lightbox-gallery and simple-react-lightbox are not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, gallery, lightbox

I was trying in my react project to had an adaptive gallery that had also a lightbox when clicked on, i tried to use **react-lightbox-gallery** and it worked but not quite, when i inserted the src: "" manually was fine, when i tried to push inside an array of object and passed into the gallery component they didn't showed up, the only way they showed up was when i pass manually the first object and then push the others. In that case if i clicked on the only one rendered and then close the lightbox would render the other pushed missing images.

Then i tried to change into **simple-react-lightbox** and it won't even show up in the DOM, it's just an empty div.

*****UPDATE*** : The component won't load unless i change the viewport size.**

https://streamable.com/asibpx

**Video of the problem.**

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { SRLWrapper } from "simple-react-lightbox";

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Gallery extends Component {

    render() {

        var images = [];

        axios.get("http://localhost:80/api/main.php").then(res => {

            res.data.forEach(element => {

                images.push({

                    src: "http://" + window.location.hostname + '/media/images/andes/' + element,
                    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                    width: 'auto',
                    height: 'auto'

                });

            });

        }).catch(error => console.log(error));

        console.log(images);

        return (

            <div>

                <SRLWrapper elements={images} />

            </div>

        );

    }
}
```

Here's the index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import SimpleReactLightbox from 'simple-react-lightbox';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from "react-router-dom";

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './customCss/custom.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <SimpleReactLightbox>
        <App />
      </SimpleReactLightbox>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I needed to use **setState** and not directly push on a variable, for some reason they can't be read singularly and for some other reasons changing viewport would make them readable...